# Privacy of data for Azure Cognitive Speech Services

Tags: azure, privacy, azure-cognitive-services

In our company want to use the Azure Speech service for ASR of Kids' speech. In our agreement with the parents for this project (and also per company policy), we need to be sure the WAV data (and transcriptions) we send to Cloud based services like this one are not stored nor logged nor kept in any way by the service provider. i could not find information of what info is stored when we use the REST API or Speech API going to the Azure Speech service. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other comment, if you want to have complete control over the data and when it gets deleted you can create your own storage account and use [Azure's Bring Your Own Storage feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-encryption-of-data-at-rest#bring-your-own-storage-byos-for-customization-and-logging). This way your speech services account use the storage account that you created for all storage instead of having its own internal storage.

You can then do something like [setting up a storage policy that deletes everything inside the storage after x number of days](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/immutable-policy-configure-version-scope?tabs=azure-portal#configure-a-default-time-based-retention-policy) to make sure nothing is being kept.